# ¿Como puedo leer los argumentos especificados en un String?

Tags: javascript, string

Básicamente lo que estoy intentando hacer es, del siguiente string:

> `--metodo: youtube --busqueda: best music mix`

Obtener el "método", que tendría que devolver `youtube` y la "búsqueda", que tendría que devolver `best music mix`

Como si se tratase de especificar parámetros a la hora de ejecutar un comando.

Entonces el resultado esperado sería un objeto con la siguiente info:

```js
{
 metodo: "youtube",
 busqueda: "best music mix" 
}
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar a hacer esto de la manera más automática posible (sin usar .replace().. etc). gracias.

Comment: Si la pregunta apunta a si ya existe algo nativo para "parsear" una cadena con dicho formato, la respuesta es no.

Comment: No, me refiero a que, quiero encontrar la manera más eficiente (no usar loops por ej) para hacer esto

Comment: La solución más eficiente depende de muchos factores, por ejemplo de la longitud de la cadena, la cantidad de casos a _parsear_, etc. etc. ¿Que has intentado? Por favor, comparte tu código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se me ocurre que podrías hacer algo así

```js
let str = "--metodo: youtube --busqueda: best music mix";

let objSalida = {};

let sp1 = str.split('--');
sp1.forEach(S => {
  if (S == '') return;
  let sp2 = S.split(':');
  objSalida[sp2[0].trim()] = sp2[1].trim();
})

console.log(objSalida);
```

Por claridad del código no he hecho comprobaciones y he supuesto que el string de entrada *str* está bien formado y no contiene errores. He usado un loop forEach sólo para permitir un número indeterminado de parámetros.

El funcionamiento es sencillo, primero divido el string de entrada en substrings tomando como separador el doble guión. Luego divido cada substring usando como separador los dos puntos, la parte de la izquierda será el nombre del parámetro y la de la derecha su valor. Estos items los añado a un objeto que será la salida buscada. Espero que se entienda. Un saludo.

Comment: Funciona perfecto y me sirve a la perfección, gracias!

Comment: La respuesta es correcta. Pero la idea es que el OP demuestre que primero a intentando resolver su problema. La comunidad intenta no realizar el trabajo de otros sino ayudarlos. PD: Si una pregunta merece tu tiempo para una respuesta, probablemente también merece tu voto.